# Voting on a webpage from R

Tags: html, r, selenium, rvest, rcurl

I would like to vote particular comments on a web portal of a local television using R.

Let's say I have the following link to comments related to the particular news.

```
url1 <- "http://rs.n1info.com/Comment/StandardComment/637905/Sci-Tech/Facebook-ce-dati-prednost-verodostojnim-medijskim-kucama.html"
```

Let's say I want to vote up for the comment posted by ***eto***. Manually I can do it with a mouse click on a green arrow below the comment.

I have no experience connecting R with webpages and send commands to them. I tried to use the ***rvest*** package and hopefully selected nodes related to voting up command but I have no clue what to do next.

```
library('rvest')
webpage <- read_html(url1, encoding = "UTF-8")

vote.up.icon.nodes <- html_nodes(webpage, '.comment-likes-icon') # select all 'vote up icon' nodes usin css
```

I am not sure how to **select the particular comment** (e.g. form ***eto***) and **how to send a command to vote up** form R.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing that is usually a violation of website's terms of service. Have you made sure this is allowed?

Comment: @Gregor Your point makes sense but honestly, I don't know does it violate terms of service.

Comment: @Gregor I went through portal's terms of service and there is nothing related to this issue.